# PhpStorm auto-import is not working for NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm learning NextJS, and using PhpStorm for development. I never had problem with React auto-import since now. But my IDE doesn't seem to detect NextJS for auto-import components and classes.

I created my project using `yarn create next-app` and created a new really basic page with `<h1>Hello World</h1>` and wanted to add a `<Link>` and `<Image>` but both are not suggested in auto-import.

It seem nothing like that, but I really need this for creating a whole project. So wanted to know if you have any suggestion to fix that issue?

Comment: I have the same question!

Comment: Even WebStorm does not recognize them :(